# iTunes thinking two distinct apps are the same one

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an iPhone app that I created by copying an xCode project to another location and then renaming the project, executable, product etc. Lets say the original and the copy are app A and app B. If I install A to my phone with an ad hoc provisioning file, it installs and runs fine. The same is true for B. But if I first install A and then try to install B, it tells me B is already installed. Also, if I right click on B in iTunes and look at the .ipa file that is created, it is sometimes the same one that is created for A. So these two apps share something in common but I cant figure out what it is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone identifies apps by the Bundle Identifier (also called the App ID) in the apps Info.plist.  You can change this in Xcode in your Target Property Settings.